# Flex SDK 3.5 builds bigger swfs

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an application which is almost entirely in actionscript.
When I build it using Flex SDK 3.5 its size is roughly 378 KB,
While Flex SDK 3.0 outputs a swf with roughly 355 KB.
What could the reason be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because more code has been
added to the existing classes.